# Is it possible to provide spring data with runtime-created @Entity classes?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Im working on a system that uses byte buddy to generate some classes on runtime, specially entities, that are created from a json schema file. My question is, can I provide to Spring Data the classes generated by bytebuddy or it will only work if the classes exist in disk at startup?